# Jquery :first doesn't work in my case

Tags: jquery

this is my markup https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ1xT.png

and I tried `console.log($('.post-form').find('p:first').val());` and I can't get the logged as value?

Comment: Use the `text` method instead of the `val`. `val` works for getting value of form elements.

Comment: why do not you post your code here cuz link will be expired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p></p>` not have value attribute it's text/html container. So you should try to get the inner text.

Try this:

```
console.log($('.post-form').find('p:first').text());
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3mk1da6d/)

OR if you want to get the  `innerHtml` part also (but as per your image no need to use `.html()`) then you can use:

```
console.log($('.post-form').find('p:first').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log($('.post-form').find('p:first').html());
```

or

```
console.log($('.post-form').find('p:eq(0)').html());
```